# Icon missing in listview for jQuery mobile 1.4

Tags: jquery-mobile

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Yz3W/3/). And here's the code:

```
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li>One</li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
</ul>
```

The ui-icon-carat-r is not showing up for item two.
I think what I'm supposed to do is load my css that I downloaded from themeroller followed by the jQuery mobile structure css.

I have uploaded all the images in icons-png, and I don't see any errors in my console.

Answer (score -1):

I had to include jquery.mobile.icons.min.css.